# AmazonServiceException class not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS SDK to upload files to S3 bucket when set java classpath to "aws-java-sdk-1.10.49.jar", the program works fine, but when replacing jar file to a later version "aws-java-sdk-1.11.35.jar", I get an exception "AmazonServiceException class not found as below."

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonServiceException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

any help?

Comment: Do you have two versions of the AWS SDK on the classpath?

Comment: No, one version as follows: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -classpath ./commons-httpclient.jar:${LIBDIR}/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:./commons-logging.jar:./log4j-1.2.17.jar:./commons-codec-1.8.jar:./aws-java-sdk-1.11.35.jar:./aws-java-sdk-s3-1.11.35.jar:./jackson-databind-2.5.
3.jar:./jackson-core-2.5.3.jar:./jackson-annotations-2.5.0.jar:./httpclient-4.3.3.jar:./httpcore-4.3.2.jar:./javax.jms-1.1
.jar:/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib-1.0.0.jar:./commons-io-2.4.jar:./javax.json-1.0.4.jar:./json-simple-1.1.1.jar awss3.testUpload

Answer (score 1):

here we have three possible problems:

1. A simple example of NoClassDefFoundError is class belongs to a missing JAR file or JAR was not added into classpath or sometimes jar's name has been changed by someone like in my case one of my colleagues has changed tibco.jar into tibco_v3.jar and the program is failing with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError and I were wondering what's wrong.
2. The class is not in Classpath, there is no sure shot way of knowing it but many times you can just have a look to print System.getproperty("java.classpath") and it will print the classpath from there you can at least get an idea of your actual runtime classpath.
3. Just try to run with explicitly -classpath option with the classpath you think will work and if it's working then it's a sure short sign that someone is overriding java classpath.

Take a look at [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html) article

Comment: Thanks, i just created another project and added all Maven dependencies and run the program works fine, but for that first program still complaining about classNotFound!!!! i am sure i explicitly specified aws-java-sdk-1.11.23.jar in java CLASSPATH. FYI.. program works well in Eclipse, the problem happen when run in Linux